# I am trying to fetch information from phpmyadmin database, but in browser it's showing cannot get/employee and in command prompt there is no error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, phpmyadmin

```
    const { json } = require('express/lib/response');
    const mysql=require ('mysql');
const express=require('express');
var app=express();
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.json());

var mysqlConnection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password:'',
    database: 'employee_db'
});
mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{
    if(!err)
    {
        console.log("DB connection is successfull");
    }
    else{
        console.log("DB connection failed "+JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
    }
});
app.listen(8000,()=>console.log('Express server is running on port number: 8000'));
app.get('/employess',(res,req)=>{
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE',(err,rows,fields)=>{
        if(!err)
        {
            console.log(rows);
        }
        else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
});
```

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS E:\Development\crud-node> node index.js
Express server is running on port number: 8000
DB connection is successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there seems to be spelling mistake in end point. The one you specified in error detail and the one defined in the code are different